# JSF RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

When I write `<h:outputText value="Login Name"/>` tag in my JSP, I get the following exception message:

```
Cannot find FacesContext
```

Without that my JSP works fine. Here is my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
    <body>
        Login Name <input type="text" value=""/><br>
        <h:outputText value="Login Name"/>
        Password<input type="password" value=""/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no question here, and virtually no helpful text or clues.  Code-vomit.

Comment: @BalusC: IMHO bad title made him frustrated

Comment: @Roman: The code was originally posted without code tags and which made it unreadable. Sunny Mate didn't pay attention to formatting at all. Skaffman fixed it. Check the bottom of question revision history: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2424455/revisions

Answer (score 5):

There are two flaws in your code:

1. The root cause of this exception is that you forgot to pass the request through the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml`. If the JSP page is for example named `page.jsp` and the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` is for example `*.jsf`, then you need to invoke it by `http://example.com/context/page.jsf` instead of `.jsp`. This way the `FacesServlet` will be invoked and create the `FacesContext`. Otherwise the JSF components in the page will complain that the `FacesContext` cannot be found and you will face this particular exception.
2. The `<f:view>` is missing in the page. Wrap the entire `<html>` in it. E.g.

   ```
    <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
    <!doctype ... >
    <f:view>
        <html>
            ...
        </html>
    </f:view>
   ```

By the way, that `import` attribute in the `<%@page>` is completely superfluous. Get rid of it.