# Exporting JSF project as WAR file ends up in RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext

Tags: eclipse, jsf, war

When I export my JSF 1.2 project as WAR file, it is not being created properly in Eclipse Indigo. Namely, when I import it again and run it, then it ends up in the "FacesContext not found" error. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why exactly do you think that the particular error is related to the WAR export? This particular error is just result of calling a wrong URL. See also [JSF RuntimeException: Cannot find FacesContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424455/jsf-runtimeexception-cannot-find-facescontext)

Comment: I think that way because when I export it in the faces-config.xml file there are multiple tabs coming such as "ManagedBean","Navigation Rule","source" etc. When I import it back there is only one tab in faces-config.xml. that is "source". Any idea? i am new to this,did i miss any basic things??

Comment: This is not related to the concrete problem. Did you use the right URL in browser's address bar? I.e. the one actually matcing the `FacesServlet` URL pattern? Did you read and understand the answer to the question linked in my previous comment?

Comment: I checked again, when I import it again and run the url pattern is missing /faces/ . when i append it manually it is coming fine. is there any way in which the url pattern will come same in the imported file also? Thanks a lot BalusC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I checked again, when I import it again and run the url pattern is missing /faces/ . when i append it manually it is coming fine. is there any way in which the url pattern will come same in the imported file also?*

You're relying too much on the IDE doing all the necessary magic for you. Your initial project had the JSF project facet set and you were running the project by *Run on server* using the builtin browser instead of just starting the server and navigate to it yourself in the external browser.

The JSF project facet is an Eclipse specific feature which is completely unrelated to the JSF/Servlet spec. This information is nowhere stored in the WAR. When you import it again, it'll become a default dynamic web project without any specific project facets set. You need to rightclick the project, go to *Project Facets* section and manually add the JSF project facet. This way the IDE becomes aware that the project is a JSF project and will do the necessary magic such as automagically inlining the `FacesServlet` mapping in the target URL during *Run As*.